# Adding up the elements of an array of pointers to integer objects

Tags: c++, arrays

I am having a tough time doing this.
Basically I have a class called "integer" that's derived from an abstract base class called "Item".
I am trying to add up all the elements of an array of pointers to integer object as follows:

```
class Item
{
public:
    virtual void print() = 0; 
    virtual string getType() = 0; 
    virtual Item* add(Item *item) = 0; 
};

class integer: public Item {
private:
    int data;
public:
    integer(int _data): data(_data){;}
    void print () {
        cout << data << "\n";
    }
    string getType() {
        return "INTEGER";
    }
    integer* add(Item *item) {
        if(this -> getType() != item -> getType()) {
            throw "TYPE MISMATCH" ;
        }   
        integer* tempInt = dynamic_cast<integer*>(item);
        return new integer(this -> data + tempInt -> data);
    }
};

void printAll(Item** items, int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        items[i] -> print();
}

void addPrintAll(Item ** items, int n) {
    Item* p = items[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        p = p -> add(items[i]);
    }
    p -> print();
}

void main()
{   
    int n = 10;
    Item **integers = new Item*[n]; 
    Item **strings = new Item*[n]; 

    // populate lists
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        integers[i] = new integer(i);
    }

try
    {
        printAll(integers, n);      // print integers
        addPrintAll(integers, n);   // add integers
    }
    catch(char *e)
    {
        cout << e;
    }
}
```

Now on that line in the addPrintAll function:

```
p = p -> add(items[i]);
```

I am repeatedly calling the new operator on p without deleting, thus causing memory leaks.
Any better ways of doing this?

Comment: Use `std::vector`s and smart pointers.

Comment: @vsoftco This is an assignment and I am forced to use C-style arrays and pointers :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement an operator+=() for the class. In Item it will be undefined:

```
virtual Item& operator+=(Item& other) = 0;
```

In integer class implement it:

```
Item& operator+=(Item& other) {
    if(other.getType() != getType()) {
        throw "TYPE MISMATCH" ;
    }
    data += dynamic_cast<integer&>(other).data;
    return *this;
}
```

And in main, inside the try block, use it like this:

```
    integer sum(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        sum += *integers[i];
    sum.print();
```